# fancybox opening on refresh not click

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've been sitting for days going through blogs, code, forum anything that would help me solve the problem.

What I'm trying to do is show a thum image on a page with a summary of information, that on click a bigger image opens in fancybox.

But I have all images in a mysql database and a php page that calls them, here's the code and scripts I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox({ href: "/images/big_pic.php?id=905", type: "image"})
});
</script>

<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/images/big_pic.php?id=905"><img src="h/images/small_pic.php?id=905" alt="" /></a>
```

I have the thumb showing and on page refresh it goes to the fancybox, but on click goes to the /images/big_pic.php?id=905.

I am wanting to use fancybox on several sites and want to buy the licence, but there's no point in buying it if it won't work! Going absolutely nuts with this.

Hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). You need to have at least this jQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      type: "image"
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

2). If you also want the link to show fancybox on page load, just `trigger` a `click` on the same selector like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         type: "image"
     }).trigger("click"); // <-- show fancybox on page load. Then after every click on the link
 });
</script>
```

... and you will have the double functionality you are looking for.

3). On the other hand, if you have a *gallery* and you are triggering it on page load, use the method `.eq()` to make sure that the first element of the gallery will be triggered like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         type: "image"
     }).eq(0).trigger("click"); // <-- show fancybox on page load starting from the first element
 });
</script>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RLc7c/)**

Comment: It WORKS!! Thank you so much for this JFK the first option is what I was stuggling with, but can see where I would use the others. This has really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the line `$.fancybox({...` triggers the lightbox on load but you're not actually making specific links "lightbox" links yet. Add the extra line pointed out below to your JS section to resolve this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox({ href: "/images/big_pic.php?id=905", type: "image"});
$(".fancybox").fancybox(); // <--- this line should do the trick
});
</script>
```

Comment: No I'm sorry that didn't work it's still opening the Fancybox on load?

Comment: @Vicki: you don't want that to happen?